# Mailchimp form not submitting

Tags: html, forms, mailchimp, submission

I am trying to integrate MailChimp into a simple web site with form for submitting one's email to get more information.

However, even after integration into existing web site form, it still does not submit any info to the List that has been setup on the MailChimp system.

Since the integration into existing form did not work, I decided to go back a step and simply test the vanilla code that was produced by MailChimp - but even this will not work, so I did a search and found that this is a common problem with MailChimp as described on their web site:

QUOTE 'My form isn't doing anything after someone clicks the "Subscribe" button.

After clicking the Subscribe button on your embed code form, if your subscribers don't see any error or success messages, aren't redirected to your Signup Thank You Page, and don't receive your Opt-In Confirmation Email, the form may not have submitted to our servers as expected. This typically occurs when there are multiple forms that utilize JavaScript validation on a single page.

If you'd like to have more than one embedded form on a single page, you'll need to either disable JavaScript for the Classic Form, place your form in an iFrame on your website, or utilize one of the other embed code forms such as the Naked Form or Super Slim Form. These two forms don't utilize any JavaScript in their code.'  END QUOTE

The issue is that I am already using the Super Slim Form (i.e. with no JavaScript), and there are not any other forms on the page that could possibly conflict - so the MailChimp solution that is offered is not applicable.

And here is the vanilla code provided by MailChimp:

```
<!-- Begin MailChimp Signup Form -->
<link href="//cdn-images.mailchimp.com/embedcode/slim-081711.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<style type="text/css">
    #mc_embed_signup{background:#fff; clear:left; font:14px Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; }
    /* Add your own MailChimp form style overrides in your site stylesheet or in this style block.
       We recommend moving this block and the preceding CSS link to the HEAD of your HTML file. */
</style>
<div id="mc_embed_signup">

<form action="//test.us9.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=7d8e5d2a8c2b79eb3827e261b&amp;id=77e030126f" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
    <div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">
    <label for="mce-EMAIL">Subscribe to our mailing list</label>
    <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="email" id="mce-EMAIL" placeholder="email address" required>
    <!-- real people should not fill this in and expect good things - do not remove this or risk form bot signups-->
    <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;"><input type="text" name="b_7d8e5d2a8c2b79eb3827e261b_77e030126f" tabindex="-1" value=""></div>
    <div class="clear"><input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button"></div>
    </div>
</form>

</div>

<!--End mc_embed_signup-->
```

Can anyone help me to understand why this seemingly simple set up is not working?

Answer (score 2):

Try using `http:` or `https:` in the action like this:

```
action="http://test.us9.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=7d8e5d2a8c2b79eb3827e261b&amp;id=77e030126f"
```

Comment: Did that with a form with the same issue. This did not change the issue. Not sure if it did for the OP either.